# Distinct counts per year

Tags: sql-server

hello I am trying to count a person only once even if a person has two enrollments in the same year:

```
    select  DISTINCT Year, School,
    count (case when [Graduate]= 1 AND [Dropout]= 0 THEN ID END) As  'passed',
    count (case when [Graduate]= 0 AND [Dropout]= 1 THEN ID END) as 'dropped',
     count (case when [Graduate]= 0 AND [Dropout]= 0 THEN ID END) as 'Continued'
    from Table where ID = '10'
    group by Year, School

my output is    
Year    school  passed   dropped   continued
2012    School    0         0          1
2013    School    0         0          1
2014    School    0         0          2
```

continued is 2 for ID=1 because student enrolled twice. How do i get a distinct count in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `DISTINCT` wrong, it should be inside each `COUNT`:

```
SELECT  [Year], 
        School,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Graduate] = 1 AND [Dropout] = 0 THEN ID END) Passed,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Graduate] = 0 AND [Dropout] = 1 THEN ID END) Dropped,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Graduate] = 0 AND [Dropout] = 0 THEN ID END) Continued
FROM YourTable 
WHERE ID = '10'
GROUP BY [Year], 
         School;
```

Comment: Hello Lamak, Thank you, that fixes my problem. Can i know teh difference between using it inside and outside?

Comment: @sweety well, they are completely different, outside you are saying that you the result of the `SELECT` should have only unique rows. Inside the `COUNT` means that you are counting only different `ID`s

Comment: Thank you, I understand that. I will do my study to udnerstand differences between count(distinct) and distinct count.